# jQuery, lots of children. What is a better way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a better way to do...

`$(el).children('.thing').children('.thing').children('.thing').children('.thing')`

Thanks

Comment: simple nested divs, or other dom elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(el).find('> .thing > .thing > .thing > .thing');
```

Comment: @Francis I don't see why this way should be better ?